# Print the last 1,2,3..Nth or first 1,2,3...Nth matching block pattern using awk or sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

pattern1
a
b
pattern2
cd
pattern1
re
pattern2
gh
pattern1
ef
pattern2
qw
e

**I can show all matching pattern by**

```
sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p'
```

**Choose the second matching pattern or any Nth by**

```
awk -vM=2 '(x+=/pattern1/)==M&&x+=/pattern2/' file
```

pattern1
re
pattern2

**Print only last matching pattern by**

```
awk 'x+=/pattern1|pattern2/{!y++&&B="";B=B?B"\n"$0:$0;x==2&&y=x=0}END{print B}' file
```

pattern1
ef
pattern2

**But how can I print for example the last/first 2 or Nth matching block pattern?**
pattern1
re
pattern2
pattern1
ef
pattern2

Comment: Edit you question to show what have you tried. Then we can help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/{p;/pattern2/{H;x;s///2;x;T;q}}' file
```

This prints the first 2 matches of `pattern1` through `pattern2` and then quits.

```
sed -nr '/pattern1/,/pattern2/H;$!b;x;s/.*((pattern1.*){2})$/\1/p' file
```

This prints the last 2 matches of `pattern1` through `pattern2`.